# How do I take $\dfrac d{dx}W(x+\ln|x+2|+c)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So 4 days ago, I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828255/a-troubling-differential-equation-xy2yx2y-e-yx3) question on how to solve the differential equation$$(xy+2y+x+2)y'=e^{-y}(x+3)$$which I was able to solve, with the solution being$$W(x+\ln|x+2|+b),b=c_0-c_1$$where $W(z)$ is Lambert's $W$ function, however I don't know how to verify this answer.

Sure, as @Moo mentioned, all I have to do is plug in $W(x+\ln|x+2|+b)$ into the original equation, but that involves taking $\frac d{dx}W(x+\ln|x+2|+b)$, which I don't know how to do.

So my question is: How do I go about taking $\frac d{dx}W(x+\ln|x+2|+b)$, where $W(z)$ is Lambert's $W$ function, also known as the product log function?

Comment: Use the fact that the Lambert W function is an inverse function of $\ xe^x$. You can then write $\ We^W = x+ ln(x+2)+b$  and differentiate both sides, obtaining your required expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lambert W function, by definition, is the inverse of the function

$$\ f(x) = xe^x$$

This means that

$$\ W(x+\ln|x+2|+b) \cdot e^{W(x+\ln|x+2|+b)} = x+\ln|x+2|+b$$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $\ x$, we get:

$$\ W'(x+\ln|x+2|+b) \cdot (1 + \frac{1}{|x+2|}) \cdot e^{W(x+\ln|x+2|+b)} + W(x+\ln|x+2|+b) \cdot( e^{W(x+\ln|x+2|+b)} \cdot W'(x+\ln|x+2|+b) \cdot (1 + \frac{1}{|x+2|}) = 1 + \frac{1}{|x+2|}$$

$$\  W'(x+\ln|x+2|+b) \cdot [(1 + \frac{1}{|x+2|}) \cdot e^{W(x+\ln|x+2|+b)} + W(x+\ln|x+2|+b) \cdot( e^{W(x+\ln|x+2|+b)}\cdot (1 + \frac{1}{|x+2|})] = 1 + \frac{1}{|x+2|}$$

You can retrieve $\ W'(x+\ln|x+2|+b)$ by moving the expression to the RHS.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use the chain rule.

Since
$$\frac d {dt} W(t)=\frac{W(t)}{t \,(1+W(t))}$$ then
$$\frac d {dx} W(f(x))=\frac{W(f(x))\,\, f'(x)}{f(x)\,\, (1+W(f(x)))}$$